# perl can't get SSL socket on linux

Tags: linux, perl, sockets, ssl

Apache accesses sites with ssl and the certificate seems fine, but I cannot get it to work with perl/cgi.  I get the following error:

```
LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: connect: Connection timed out at
/usr/local/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 52.
```

The code causing this error:

```
my $useragent = LWP::UserAgent->new("local_address" => "$local_ip");
my $request = POST( $post_url, $post_values );
my $reply_data = $useragent->request( $request );
```

although i've tried it with and without passing the local address.  I noticed the LWP function didn't dump the local address in debugging, so I specifically handed it over, but the same problem happens either way.

I'm always using:

```
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use LWP::UserAgent;
```

and I've tried with and without

```
use NET::SSL;
```

Tried this with and without passing the port:

```
@LWP::Protocol::https::EXTRA_SOCK_OPTS = (LocalAddr => '$local_ip',
            #LocalPort => '443' );
```

To make sure perl is seeing the certificate, I've tried this:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
ssl_opts => {
    #SSL_use_cert => 1,
    #SSL_cert_file   => "path-to-cert.crt",
    #SSL_key_file    => "path-to-key.key",
    },
);
```

as well as environment variables:

```
$ENV{PERL_NET_HTTPS_SSL_SOCKET_CLASS}="IO::Socket::SSL";
$ENV{HTTPS_CERT_FILE} = "path-to-cert.crt";
$ENV{HTTPS_KEY_FILE} = "path-to-key.key";
```

Also randomly tried this:
    $ENV{PERL_NET_HTTPS_SSL_SOCKET_CLASS}="IO::Socket::SSL";

I've tried two different versions of perl (5.10.1 and 5.24.1)

and installed openssl 1.0.2j

Someone suggested this workaround:

```
# workaround for ssl bug
use LWP::Protocol::https10 ();
LWP::Protocol::implementor('https', 'LWP::Protocol::https10');
```

but it didn't work.

There is no firewall or anything that I know about configured on linux that would prevent outward bound sockets, but I feel like this is where the problem must be.

I watched the program go through the perl debugger and it appears to be cycling through all of the ports over and over until it hits a timeout.

Please help!!!!  I'm going insane.  Does anyone know of something at the linux system level that could be causing me to be unable to use ssl from perl?

P.S.  Also tried adding this to my user agent:

```
ssl_opts =>  {verify_hostname => 0},
protocols_allowed => ["https"]
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the exact same code was in production and working fine on a different linux server.  Verio "migrated" my server and broke many things.

Comment: What do you mean by "cycling through the ports"?

Comment: There are hundreds (thousands?) of attempts to bind to a socket with lots of different port numbers.

Comment: Connection timed out is a problem at the TCP level already and not related to SSL settings at all. This means that fiddling with certificates, openssl version etc will not help. If a web browser can access the site **from the same machine** then check if the browser is using a proxy and your script not or the other way around and if there is a proxy involved make sure that they use the same proxy settings. If a proxy is involved make also sure that you have at least LWP version 6.06.

Comment: What do you mean, "attempts to bind with different port numbers"? It should only be binding to port 0 (which tells the OS to provide a free port). Furthermore, there should only be one call to `bind` per socket, so what makes you think it tries to bind the same socket more than once?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Stephen Ullrich - it was a tcp configuration issue.  The resolvers were configured incorrectly; with the right addresses in there everything is working.

(It would have bene really nice to get an error message of some kind, or at least know where the timeout was coming from...)

Thanks to those who commented!

Comment: If the resolver returns the wrong address and this address exists but simply drops packets then it is impossible to get from the TCP stack and thus the Perl program a better message than that the attempt to reach the server timed out, i.e. exactly what you got.  The program does not know the underlying reason, i.e. if there is no such server, if there is a firewall blocking traffic, if the internet is slow or if it is a configuration error like in your case and thus cannot give a message which points to the real problem.

Comment: Interesting, thanks, and makes sense.  However it would be possible (right?) and fabulously helpful to return something like "TCP: connection attempt timed out" rather than "connection timed out in ..perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm".   It's certainly possible that I should have extrapolated the problem from that message and I'm just not linux-savvy enough to have done so, but it would be better for the error handling to be more explicit.  If you can't report the problem, you can at least say where it happened.